# Sorting a Hashmap which has objects as values

Tags: java, android, sorting, hashmap

I want to sort the entries in a hashmap by the value of an object's property.

Here is my HashMap:

```
final Map<String, Seasons> = new HashMap<>();
```

Here is my Seasons class:

```
public class Seasons {

private int results;
private int scores;
private int points;

public Seasons() {
}

//getters and setters

}
```

So I want to sort the hashmap in terms of each entries 'points'.

I have seen the topic that's been marked as a possible duplicate of this. I tried to use that but couldn't manage to adapt it to use it in my case.

Comment: You need a comparable interface for the seasons object.

Comment: I'm fairly inexperienced with Java. Could you explain further please?